# HTML Title tooltip gets cut off after spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get some specific title text to display via JavaScript, but I'm having some issues getting the entire string to show up.

The text I'm trying to display:

> mechanical : Failed to copy

And here's what shows up in HTML:

```
`<td title="mechanical" :="" failed="" to="" copy="">mechanical : Failed to copy</td>`
```

The actual title displayed afterwards is just `mechanical`.

In Javascript:

```
var copyResult = json_obj[i].CopyResult; //variable that contains the text
copyResult = copyResult.replace(/["{}]/g, " "); //regex that removes some characters and replaces them with spaces
```

The `copyResult` variable is then added to the element I want.

It looks like having spaces "ends" the title attribute, so the browser tries to make more attributes with the remaining text.

**What's the best way to fix this?**

Comment: well the title has mechanical in quotes. If something is NOT quoted than it stops at the whitespace....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to create a workaround. Since *any* space would end the title attribute, I simply used a regex to properly escape all of the space characters for the `copyResult` variable.

```
var copyResult = copyResult.replace(/[ ]/g,"\u00a0")
```

`\u00a0` is the [Unicode character for `NO-BREAK-SPACE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).

Comment: The string is inserted without quotes, and I can't change the value of the string I have to insert.

Comment: So you can not change the code that uses the variable??

Comment: It's part of the codebase I'm working with. I understand what you're getting at, but it looks like this particular situation has to be solved this way.

Comment: Using a hammer to open a window works too. Sometimes it is better to fix the route problem. But it you are happy with not quoting attributes and using unicodes go ahead, it is not my code base.

Answer (score 1):

it's not the spaces ending the atribute, its the quotation marks... try escaping them with backslashes like `\"`

Comment: Actually I think you would have to replace quotes with their html entity code ```&quot;```

Comment: it's also a valid option ;)

Comment: There are no quotation marks in the text I'm putting into the title attribute, though. The only string I have is `mechanical : Failed to copy`

Comment: @Thassa Because it needs to be quoted..... How is a parser supposed to know that all those characters belong as an attribute???